# flyway error: Unable to obtain connection from database for user 'null'

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, flyway, configmap

im trying to run flyway `docker image 7.3.2` against a postgres db on kubernetes:

When i run the job my output is:

```
Flyway Community Edition 7.3.2 by Redgate
ERROR:
Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://xxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/xxx flyway.user=postgres flyway.password=****************) for user 'null': The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08004
Error Code : 0
Message    : The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

the settings it outputs are correct and should enable a connection.

I pass in my `flyway.conf` via a configmap which is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: flyway-configmap
data:
  flyway.conf:
    flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/xxx
    flyway.user=postgres
    flyway.password=xxx
```

anyone able to assist in what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is literally your `ConfigMap`, then it is missing the `|` character after the `:` which would make that yaml key into [a newline delimited scalar](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/block/literal). That theory also squares up with your error message showing that the **entire thing** is taken as the value of `flyway.url`

What you want:

```yaml
  flyway.conf: |
    flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/xxx
    flyway.user=postgres
    flyway.password=xxx
```